# Node.js Error in routing

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

First of all sorry it is a beginners question yet I cannot seem to get out by myself. 
I am working on an app that will dispatch messages according to one specific parameter in Json. I have the following in app.config.json

```
<code>
{
    "server": {
        "port": "8080"
    },
    "auth":{
        "users": {
            "xxx": "xxxxx"
        },
        "unauthorizedResponse": "Unauthorized!"
    },
  "services": {
    "service one": { 
        "address": "http://localhost",
        "port": "8000"
    }

}


}
</code>
```

And the router is:

```
<code>
const request = require('request');
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require("fs");
const configs = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../app.config.json', 'utf8'));

const services = configs.services;



router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let serviceName = req.get('service-name');

    if (services[serviceName]) {

        let requestOptions = {
            uri: services[serviceName].address + ":" + services[serviceName].port,
            json: req.body
        }
        request.post(requestOptions, (error, response, body) => {

            res.send(body);
        });
    } else {
        res.send("There is no service named " + req.get("service-name"))
    }

});

module.exports = router;

</code>
```

My problem is I am trying to add more services to app.config.json that ends up giving me the following error:

```
undefined:20
    "service2": {
    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 313
</code>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Worked!Thank you ver much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing a `,` in the JSON object. Let's try this:

```
"service one": { 
    "address": "http://localhost",
    "port": "8000"
},
"service two": { 
        "address": "http://localhost/route2",
        "port": "8000"
    }
```